# For iOS developers, are there many differences between XCode 4.2 (iOS5) and XCode 4.5 (iOS6)?

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm starting to learn iOS development using this awesome course on iTunes U:
http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/

However, this course was done in Fall 2011 and is using XCode 4.2 and iOS5.
I now see that XCode 4.5 (iOS6) is out.

I just want to know if it's a good thing following this course as it's already one year old?
Or if XCode 4.2 (iOS5) and XCode 4.5 (iOS6) are so similar, that I'll just have to tweak some things a little?

I used to follow the Fall 2010 course with XCode 3.2.5 (iOS 4.2) and I stopped to start the Fall 2011... and there were so many differences that it was almost like starting over.

I just want to make sure that by investing my time in the Fall 2011 course that I'm not learning stuff I would have to learn again in iOS6.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides all of the other good info in the other answers, please be aware that Xcode 4.5 comes with an updated LLVM compiler that provides you with much improved Objective-C features. Working with properties is much easier. You no longer need to explicitly declare instance variables for properties nor do you need the @synthesize statement. The new compiler makes working with arrays and dictionaries easier plus it is easier to box basic types.

The good news is that any code you write with the older compiler of Xcode 4.2 will continue to work under the newer compiler (but not the other way around).

Also keep in mind that Xcode 4.6 will be out soon so using 4.2 will just put you further behind.

Comment: What you listed are little cool improvements (thanks for that)... are there major changes?  Some stuff I'll have to re-learn... or some stuff I learned that I'll have to trash?

Comment: Moving to the new compiler will just make things a bit easier. As I said, nothing you do now will stop working. But the new features allow you to work more efficiently. So in a small sense, there is a little re-learning. But it's nothing that can't be learned in an hour.

Comment: So the time I invest in the course is not wasted.  It pretty much works the same way in XCode 4.5, with some improvements that I'll have to learn eventually.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The Stanford course you're about to learn is great and it contains lots of subjects, both basic and advanced. I can't think of anything that's not worth learning from the course even though it's outdated - you'll just have to learn about what's new in iOS6.0 after you've come to terms with the more important foundations and basics featured in the course.

Have fun learning iOS

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the differences between the various versions, I'd suggest you check out the [Objective-C Feature Availability Index](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/ObjCAvailabilityIndex/_index.html) and the [Xcode release notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/_index.html). The major shift in Xcode 4.5 is the support for iOS 6, and you can see a list of those features in [What's New in iOS: iOS 6](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniPhoneOS/Articles/iOS6.html)

I think you'll be able to follow the Stanford class even if you're running Xcode 4.5.2 (or whatever). There are some minor differences, but most of those are just new features that you might not yet avail yourself of yet. Frankly, many (most?) of us are still deploying iOS 5 (or earlier) apps today, to ensure backwards compatibility with users with older versions of iOS on their devices, anyway, so if you focus on iOS 5 while you learn the basics, I think that's fine. So, go ahead and gain mastery of iOS 5 using that course, and when you're done, you can then go through the [WWDC 2012 videos](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/) to familiarize yourself with some iOS 6 features and new Xcode features.

The only major stumbling block that leaps out at me (if you focus on iOS 5 targets) might be [autolayout](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Articles/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853) which is an iOS 6 feature which defaults to being turned on. To avoid confusion here, whenever creating a new storyboard or NIB, you may want to turn off "autolayout". If so, go to Interface Builder, click somewhere on the background, select the "file inspector" in the right panel, and make sure the "Use Autolayout" flag is unchecked.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For the record, they just updated the [CS193P Web Site](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/)

They will make the Winter 2012-2013 course available via iTunesU:

> Winter (2012-13) quarter's lectures are currently scheduled to be made
>   available via iTunesU. Don't expect them to appear the day after the
>   first lecture, however! There is some work involved to prepare and
>   publish them. Please be patient.

That sounds cool!